# how to get the count of elements in list box

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java

working on selenium + java,. can any one help me...
I have a drop down list box, and need to get the number of elements in the list box.

```
<select id="id">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

need to get the count, ie, 3..... thanks and in advance

Comment: What you tried so far? Did google gave you any suggestions?

Comment: 5 seconds of googling (java+ selenium + title of your question) resulted in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210853/how-to-count-the-number-of-options-in-a-select-dropdown-box-in-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In watir, this can be accomplished in one line:

```
browser.select_list(:id=> 'id').options.count
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this , storing all the Web elements of Select list in a List and then getting its size.

```
List<WebElement> optionCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//select/option"));
System.out.println(optionCount.size());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
Select listBox = new Select(selectElement);
int size1 = listBox.getOptions().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
Select s = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("#id")));
List<WebElement> list = s.getOptions();
```

There you have all the elements of your dropdown, and using the size() method you'll have all the options.